# Caching assets in Laravel 4?

Tags: caching, laravel, laravel-4

In my blade templates I use the following code to link my assets. I'd like to cache my assets (no... that's not a euphemism), but not really sure how. Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
{{ HTML::style(asset('assets/styles/styles.css')) }}

{{ HTML::script(asset('assets/scripts/built.js')) }}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serving caching headers is usually done from your server.

Here's some code you can drop into your `.htaccess` file (if you're using Apache):

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType text/css                "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript  "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you! Added your snippet to my .htaccess file and installed mod_expires. Tested with Google's PageSpeed and it worked perfectly.